# How could I write a C function using the wiringPi SPI library to read the X and Y measurements from this 2-axis inclinometer?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, spi, c, wiringpi

How would one use the wiringPi SPI library (http://wiringpi.com/reference/spi-library/) to get the x and y readings from this SCA100T inclinometer?

I understand that the function wiringPiSPIDataRW() in the wiringPi SPI library performs a simulantous read and write, but if the data from the inclinometer is only 11 bits how would I get those bits from what the function returns?

This is it's datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/sca100t_inclinometer_datasheet_8261800b2_0.PDF

Comment: You need to send in byte (8 bit) multiples.  Send enough bytes to cover the command and response bits and just ignore any irrelevant received bits.  If you can't get it to work show your code and explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally am receiving data, now it's just a matter of selecting the bits that I'm interested in.

Comment: If you get a particular problem edit it into your question if you need help.